# Too many rerenders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios

i'v create a custom hook it seems the problem persists here i changed the code to a way simpler one  using fetch and it worked but it seems i did not catch the infinite loop existence , i can feel it a lot of misatkes made please point them and if possible any code refactor will be amazing

```
import { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
const Usehttp = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [error, setError] = useState(null);

  const sendRequest = useCallback(async (config, option, applyData) => {
    setLoading(true);
    setError(null);
    try {
      const data = await axios.get(config.url, {
        method: config.method ? config.method : "GET",
        body: config.body ? JSON.stringify(config.body) : null,
        headers: config.headers ? config.headers : {},
      });
      if (option === "FETCH" || option === "CREATE") {
        applyData(data);
      } else if (option === "DELETE") {
        applyData("This has been deleted successfully");
      } else if (option === "UPDATE") {
        applyData("This has been updated successfully");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      setError(error.message || "something went wrong");
    }
    setLoading(false);
  }, []);
  sendRequest();
  return {
    loading,
    error,
    sendRequest,
  };
};

export default Usehttp;
```

Comment: `sendRequest()` should be used inside a `useEffect()` callback. You cannot invoke side-effects during the render-phase, especially since this one modifies state.

Comment: it's custom hook where i'm calling this will be either in useEffect() or in method where i either delete or create  or update

Comment: What good comes from defining a state inside your hook? Pass a setter into your hook instead of defining it in a state that way it's at least usable outside of your hook...  As @PatrickRoberts said - every time your state changes your hook executes again. There are a lot of things wrong with your code. You don't seem to understand the basics of functional React. You should really read this: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

Answer (score 1):

if UseHttp is custom hook - you need to rename to useHttp, and use this hook in top level in your component;

```
function Component() {
  const { sendRequest } = useHttp();
}
```

Also you need to add dependency for you `useCallback` like `[applyData, setLoading, setError]` in `UseHttp`